# using the attribute role="menu" in a drop down menu for a Django form

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am making a signup page with `Django` and this is a part of it :

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button id="dLabel" class="form-control form-white dropdown" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Catégorie
  </button>                             
        <ul role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" name="spec">
    {%for cat in spec%}
      <li value={{cat.id}}><a href="#">{{cat.categorie}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
        </ul>                                       
</div>
```

The problem is this is not a valid method to fill the `spec` field in the form so it's always NULL whatever option i choose . So how can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be using [Select element](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#selects) instead of a dropdown. Dropdown is not designed for selecting a single option from the list, it's for displaying a list of items.

If you really want to use dropdown instead for some reason, you need to add a hidden input to your form and then add `onclick` javascript even handlers to your dropdown items, so when a user clicks on those `<li>` you catch it and manually update the hidden input value so it can be submitted.